# Grails parse JSON into domain class

Tags: json, grails, grails-domain-class

Hi Say that I have a domain class

```
class Book{
static hasOne=[author:Author]
long id
String name

}

class Author {
static hasMany=[books:Book]
long id
String name
}
```

I have a json object sent in. Can I jus do a `new Book(Json)` and not manually set the property?

Comment: You may have to use new Book(JSON.parse(params)) to get it in the right format for GORM

Answer (score 8):

Using the built-in `Grails JSON` converter makes this easier

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class BookController {
   def save = {
      def book = new Book(JSON.parse(yourJson))
      book.save(flush:true)
   }
}
```

In the code  what's happening (we're parsing a `JSON` object and setting the properties on the `Book` entity and saving

Comment: I have problems with this when Data types are involved ... since in the JSON they appear as e.g. "2020-11-11" and i get as null in the domain class aftar parsing

Comment: Nice answer, it parses childs and put them in instances too.

Answer (score -1):

use the JsonBinder:

```
def json = request.JSON;
def book= new Book();
JsonBinder.bindJSON(book, json);
```

dont forget to import these packages:

```
import grails.converters.JSON;
import com.ocom.grails.JsonBinder;
```